# Java cluster ssh library?

Tags: java, ssh, cluster-computing

Is there a Java library for running large numbers of SSH connections across a cluster?  I'm looking for something similar to the [pdsh](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html) command line tool, or the [clustershell](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/clustershell) python library.

The required functionality is something that lets you `run_ssh("command -options", listOfHosts)`, and then handles running the command across thousands of hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The best SSH tool in Java is probably JSch:

- http://www.jcraft.com/jsch

You can then easily write your own class that executes a command on a list of hosts.